# Excessive space C++ string

Tags: c++, strings

> #### Extra gaps
>
> A string is given. Write an application that will remove
> all extra spaces from this string. A space will be considered
> superfluous if: it is at the beginning of the line, before the first
> word; it is at the end of the line, after the last word; several
> spaces are located between two words (in other words, if the words are
> separated by more than one space, then all but one of the spaces is
> superfluous).

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ukrainian");
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Enter string: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ' && str[i + 1] == ' ') {
            str.erase(i, 1);
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }

    if (str[0] == ' ') {
        str.erase(0, 1);
    }

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It seems to me that this is not a very good code, maybe there is an option how to do it better?

Comment: I'd consider this code to not confirmant to the specification, since you don't do any tests at the end of the line.

Comment: A good basic attempt. **BUT** each call to `erase()` will move all the characters from that point to the end of the string down one place. So this is `O(n^2)` in terms of complexity and thus highly inefficient especially as this could be `O(n)`. As 200 says you forgot to remove extra space from the end of string.

Comment: The standard pattern for this is called `The erase remove idiom`.

Answer (score 2):

Good first attempt:

**BUT** Your implementation is `O(n²)`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)    // Explicit Loop
        str.erase(i, 1);                 // Hidden loop:
                                         // for(int j = i; j < str.size(); ++j)
```

There is a standard idiom for addressing this:

```
 auto end = std::remove(std::begin(str), std::end(str), ' ');
 str.erase(end);
```

The `remove()` part scans the string once anything that matches the criterion is moved to the end of the string and you keep scanning forward moving all the following items down `n` places where `n` is the number of items matched.

```
 // This is not the actual implementation.
 // But use this as a visualization of the implementation.
 int remvoeCount = 0;
 int loop = 0;
 for (; (loop + removeCount) < str.size(); ++loop) {
     if (str[loop + removeCount] == ' ') {
         ++removeCount;
     }
     else {
         str[loop] = str[loop + removeCount];
     }
 }
 for (; loop < str.size(); ++loop) {
     str[loop] = ' ';
 }
```

So you can see we do a single pass over the container and move all the items found to the end and move all the other items up the required number of places.

The `erase()` function then simply has to remove the items from the last point used to the end which is simply a "resize smaller" operation.

Now in the code above I use `remove()` which takes a value that you want to use. But your code is a bit more specific and you have to do some work to decide if you want to remove the item (as not all spaces should be removed). So you want to use the `remove_if()` function that takes a lambda.

```
 auto find = std::remove_if(std::begin(str), std::end(str),
             [](char) {
                 // Your code that returns true or false
                 // to say what elements should be removed.
             });

 str.erase(find); // remove all the space elements.
```

Comment: [`std::erase()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase2) (C++20) does the whole remove-erase-dance.